# Restructuring data table/entering new rows with blank values

Tags: sas

Bit of a tricky question. I need method to systematically to group,order, and create new rows of data. There are three 4 levels of stratification (c1,c2,c3,c4) and a "score" value for each iteration of stratification. It is a bit hard to articulate, so I will give you the HAVE and WANT tables

Here are the datalines tables for easy manipulation.

```
data HAVE;
   input CLASS $ FUR_COLOR $ FAMILY $ SPECIES $ NO_IN_CAPTIVITY;
   datalines;
MAMMAL BLACK WHALE KILLER_WHALE 2 
MAMMAL BLACK FELINE PUMA 3
MAMMAL BLACK APE CHIMP 5
MAMMAL BLACK APE GORILLA 3
MAMMAL BLACK APE BONOBO 3
MAMMAL RED APE ORANGUTAN 2
;
RUN;

data WANT;
   input C1 $ C2 $ C3 $ C4;
   datalines;
MAMMAL . BLACK                .
MAMMAL WHALE KILLER_WHALE 2
MAMMAL . BLACK .
MAMMAL FELINE PUMA 3
MAMMAL . BLACK .
MAMMAL APE CHIMP 5
MAMMAL APE GORILLA 3
MAMMAL APE BONOBO 3
MAMMAL . RED .
MAMMAL APE ORANGUTAN 2
;
RUN;
```

Comment: I don't get why rows `C D G 3` and `C D H 3` do not have a `D`-only row before them, could you explain pls?

Comment: `CDG3` and `CDH3` both share a `D` value for `C2`. They both rollup to `C` which rolls up to `D`. To contrast, `CEI2` shares the `C` value with the other mentioned values, but it's `C` value rolls up to `E`, so it gets a new row, unlike the others.

Comment: Hmm ok... if you came up with some (verbal or pseudo-code) algorithm it would make it easier for us to help you out.

Comment: How do the C1-C4 variables in the output relate to the variables in the input?  Why does the output have three lines that are exactly the same? What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
data want;
  set have(rename=(C2=C2_in C3=C3_in C4=C4_in SCORE=SCORE_in));
  by C2_in C3_in;
  format C1-C3 $1. SCORE 3.;

  if first.C2_in or first.C3_in then do;
    C3 = C3_in;
    output;
  end;

  C2 = C2_in;
  C3 = C4_in;
  SCORE = SCORE_in;
  output;

  drop C2_in C3_in C3_in C4_in SCORE_in;
run;
```

[image: Resulting dataset]

Comment: This seems to work. If the `HAVE` dataset isn't sorted, you have to do that before running your code. Thanks alot for the persistence Dom.!

Comment: Yes it needs to be sorted otherwise you'll get unexpected results... You're welcome, glad it works for you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `PROC SQL` and `UNION ALL` like so:

```
PROC SQL;

CREATE TABLE want AS

    SELECT
        C1, C2, C4, SCORE
    FROM
        have

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        C1, NULL, C3, NULL
        /* If your version does not support NULL, use '' */
    FROM
        have;

QUIT;
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: Resulting table doesn't look like the OP's `want` table... Also, the 2 `NULL` in the select should be `' '` and `.` (unless some other SAS version accepts `NULL`s ?)

Comment: Works on mine - I suppose my version accepts `NULL`s... Maybe you can explain how it doesn't return the `want`. I'll post an image of what I get as a result.

Comment: Interesting... What SAS version are you using? I'm on Desktop SAS 9.4. As for the results, they are not ordered as in OP's `want`, and there are 12 rows rather than 10.

Comment: Odd. I am on 9.3. I see the 12 v 10. Guess I am missing a piece of logic that was not shared in the question. Sorting can be resolved by `ORDER BY` and the OP's own logic for that, which was not shared.

Comment: Are you both on Desktop versions? I'm puzzled by this `NULL` thing... I get an error when using them in a `SELECT` clause: `ERROR: The following columns were not found in the contributing tables: NULL.`

Comment: I'm on Desktop. Maybe it is a server setting?

Comment: Hi @Nicarus. Ty for your input. I'm on 9.4 and am getting the same results as Dominic. I'm not sure the syntax for the sort order, but want the sort to result in the WANT order above. I will play with the code and let you know if I hit any luck.

Comment: @MarkRomano You need to provide a little more information (logic) for the sort and I can provide some guidance.